# Shortcut to cd (change directory)

Tags: command-line

Is there a way I can set up some shortcuts to my most used directories?

I mean "cd trunk" would always get me to my trunk location (e:\projects\work.....) from any place ?

Answer (score 3):

I believe you are not looking for a "shortcut" but a command alias.

[This post on The UNIX and Linux Forums](http://www.unix.com/windows-dos-issues-discussions/74664-what-dos-equivalent-alias-command.html) explains how to use doskey if you have the appropriate version of Windows (which I assume you're using based on the path specified.

In Linux you can use the command `alias` to create e.g. `cdt` to expand to `cd ~/projects/trunk`.
Cygwin and similar environments on Windows can do the same.

tip: for future posts please specify the OS you're on and if relevant the shell used.  Are you using plain DOS, cygwin, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

The details on your environment are very sparse, but if you use Bash or equivalent (e.g. through Cygwin), you can set `CDPATH` for this functionality.

Demonstrated:

```
~$ cd trunk
bash: cd: trunk: No such file or directory
~$ CDPATH="/projects/work"
~$ cd trunk
/projects/work/trunk
/projects/work/trunk$
```